# aws: update lambda environment variables remotely from another app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda function implemented in Nodejs. FYI, This function is used to process data for a separate web app - which is an asp.net web app which is not hosted in AWS. To process the data, the lambda function requires some information - a set of 6-10 variables - which is set as environment variables for the lambda function. Currently these environment variables are set in aws console and everything works fine. However, setting environment variables manually via console is not scalable when moving to production because the environment variables keep changing throughout the (maybe 4-6 times per day) at random intervals.

Question:
How to update the lambda function environment variables via api from the external asp.net application?

Comment: AWS Secrets Manager is great for this. The AWS SDK can pull secrets during the init stage or the handler of the Lambda. Other key value storage or APIs would also work.

Comment: The AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store is my usual place for this kind of thing. Alternatively, if its suitable to do so,  put these values into the lambda invoke payload.